# Hibernate mapping with Spring

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate

I have [this database entities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8mbA.png)

And I have mapped them in my code like this :

```
public class Wallet {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

private String name;

private double balance;

private double limit;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
private User user;
```

(I don't have "isDeleted" in Wallet, since I removed it later today, this is just a pic from the table where I still have it)

And for users
 `public class User {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)

private Long id;

private String email;

private String password;

private String username;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Settings settings;


@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user",cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<Wallet> wallets;

private byte isDeleted;`
```

I am trying to make a constructor for the Waller and put it into MySQL DB, but whatever I do I get this error "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'limit, name, user_id, id)"

Could you please help me if my mapping is wrong or what constructor I should make for Wallet, I have been trying for the last 3 hours.. Thanks in advance!
P.S:  Sorry if my post is bad I will rework it if needed any additional info.

Comment: `limit` is a MySQL keyword. Choose another column name.

Comment: Dude! Thank you so very much! That worked great! Thanks!